# Angular 2 listen web api changes

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, observable

I am creating a todo list with Angular 2 on top of an ASP.Net Core 1.0 Api. How do I allow changes made on one device to push to other devices? A push or post is made on one device, then a get is made, then other "users" will get the changes without having to manually refresh the page.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the down votes? Am I missing some etiquette? Is my question too simple?

Comment: Your question is too broad, at least that is the reason I choose in the close vote dialog.

Comment: @pezetter: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for some guidance on how to ask good questions. Typically we need to be able to see some code in order to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAPI isn't going to push data down to the clients for you. If you want to only use WebAPI, you would need to do some sort of polling on an end point, which has many downsides including performance. Luckily, there are several options for "pushing" data down to clients.

1. [socket.io](http://socket.io/)
2. [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)
3. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

You could implement any one of these on you server and have each of your clients subscribe to the channel. Once a POST is made to your WebAPI, you would publish a message on the channel and each of the subscribed clients would receive the update. You could then handle the messages appropriately on the client side.